# C# How to map inner property object to outer class with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, mapper

I have 3 classes:

```
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class CountryDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseCountryDTO
    {
        public CountryDTO Country {get; set};
    }
```

I need to map CountryDTO to CountryModel, but through BaseCountryDTO class.
I know that I can do it like this:

```
            CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>()
                .ForMember(model => model.Id, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Country.Id))
                .ForMember(model => model.Title, o => o.MapFrom(dto => dto.Country.Title));
```

But I want to do it clear, something like this:

```
// This is not working code, just my imagination :)
            CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>()
                .ForMember(model => model, dto => dto.Country));
```

Because in model can be more than 2 properties. Is there way to do it?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you very match, it works for me. It requires 2 lines of code:

CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Country);
CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>();

It would be great if it could be written in one line :)

Comment: You can try writing an extension method.

Comment: @Phil I have used `IncludeMembers` in the past. What I don't understand is if your issue is having a lot of properties with dissimilar names in source and destination (as you've mentioned), then how the `IncludeMembers` is going to help you? If you expect it to solve your problem in just two lines, then you'll still need to have similar names in the inner source and the destination.

Comment: @atiyar In objects like `CountryModel` and `CountryDTO` I have properties with similar name, here I don't have a problem) The only thing that I have a lot of these properties. So `IncludeMembers` helps me :)

Comment: @Phil If you have a properties with same name in `CountryModel` and `CountryDTO`, no matter how many they are, `CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>();` will be enough for your mapping and you do not need the `BaseCountryDTO` class and `IncludeMembers`. Have you tried using `CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>();` ?

Comment: @atiyar Without `CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Country);` I have an error `AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.`.
I can't get rid of `BaseCountryDTO`, I have `BaseCountryDTO` and `CountryDTO` inside as property.

Comment: @Phil I have updated my answer below. Please try exactly like that. See if it throws mapping exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LucianBargaoanu Helped me with the link https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers
It solved my problem.

The solution looks like:

```
CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>().IncludeMembers(s => s.Country);
CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>();
```

So the thing is we have to create a map of base class to our model with include of what we are really want to map. Then we should create a map of class which we are really need to map.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties in `CountryModel` and `CountryDTO` have same names/types, then you can configure the mapping simply as -

```
CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>();
```

You can test the mapping as -

```
CountryDTO dto = new CountryDTO { Id = 4, Title = "Something" };
CountryModel model = Mapper.Map<CountryModel>(dto);
```

It will automatically map the properties from `CountryDTO` to `CountryModel`, no matter how many they are. You don't have to manually configure mapping for any property, or go through another class like `BaseCountryDTO`.

Comment: In my case I have different name for inner property object. So it could be with name InnerData and we need to map to object with class name CountryModel.

Comment: @Phil Sorry, I had a typo in my answer - fixed `CreateMap<BaseCountryDTO, CountryModel>()` to `CreateMap<CountryDTO, CountryModel>()`.

Comment: It's good solution, but the thing is I am parsing json string into BaseCountryDTO and there is no way to not do it (for me certainly :) ) So I must write `Mapper.Map<CountryModel>(dto)` where dto is `BaseCountryDTO`, not `CountryDTO`. I understand that entity `BaseCountryDTO` is needless here, but it is mandatory in my realife code.

Comment: @Phil So, if I get it right, you are parsing `BaseCountryDTO` from JSON which has a single property (`country` or something), which in turn contains the `id`, `title`, etc properties and therefore you created the `CountryDTO` class to hold these properties. If that is the case, then I must say `IncludeMembers` will indeed suit better in your scenario.

Comment: Yes, you get it right. Beside property `CountryDTO`, entity `BaseCountryDTO` could contain a lot of other properties. And I have to map exactly `CountryDTO` to `CountryModel`. This is the problem :)